# UITableView Data only reloads (with bugs) as I scroll, and I am unable to reload data properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

### Background

I have a `UIViewController` which handles 2 `UITableView`s, both with custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses. A click event on the top table (Categories) is supposed to trigger a `reloadData` on the bottom table (Article List from an RSS feed) depending on which category is selected. What is supposed to happen is that the new data gets pulled and the relevant array is repopulated, after which the data gets displayed on the bottom table.

The data that is meant to be displayed is:

- An image
- a `UILabel` (for the date)
- A `UITextView` for the title

### 1) First problem

The list that loads by default upon starting the app loads properly (well almost but I'l get to the 'almost' in #2) but once a category is selected in the top table, the array containing the data to be displayed in the cells is rebuilt with the relevant data but the `reloadData` method does not immediately invoke the desired results. Only once scrolling downwards and then upwards does the new data show. Using debugging I can see that the data *is* being loaded correctly into the array, so I'm sure its a `UITableViewController` or `UITableViewCell` issue.

I have tried various solutions discussed here on StackOverflow, other than the obvious `self.myTableView.reloadData` the two most common being invoking ReloadData as shown below:

```
[self.myTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and also

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.myTableView reloadData];});
}
```

Each time I've attempted to call these from within the ArticlesTableViewController instance, to no success.

### 2) Second problem

DateLabel only shows on the first cell upon opening the app, and then for the dateLabel to show in the rest of the cells I actually have to scroll downwards, and then up again. Cells coming back into view from *above* then contain the dateLabel, but if a cell appears back into view from *below* then its gone again. Pretty confusing stuff.

**Here is my relevant code**

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` (in the `ArticlesTableViewController`):

```
// Method that gets fired when parsing is complete via NSNotification
- (void) parsingComplete {
//Tell the tableview to animate the changes automatically

    self.articleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:parser.articles];

    [myTableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      static  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ArticlesTableViewCell *cell = (ArticlesTableViewCell *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell){
 cell = [[ArticlesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
      NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.articleList valueForKey:@"enclosure"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

           if (imgData) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    cell.enclosure.image = image;
                [cell.enclosure setNeedsDisplay];
            });
        }
    }
});




    [cell.dateLabel setText:[[self.articleList valueForKey:@"pubDate"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.headingTextView setText:[[self.articleList valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     cell.headingTextView.editable = NO;


return cell;

 }
```

CustomCell code (for `ArticlesTableViewCell`):

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

    {

            self = [super initWithStyle:style     reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.enclosure = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,48,48)];
        self.enclosure.tag = 1;
         //self.imageView = nil;

        self.dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (75,-10,50,50)];
        self.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.dateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:8.0f];

        self.headingTextView= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 20, 400, 80)];
        self.headingTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.headingTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0f];

     [self addSubview:self.dateLabel];
        [self addSubview:self.enclosure];
        [self addSubview:self.headingTextView];


        //Here the Date only appears in the first cell, but when I scroll down and up again it re-appears
            }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT**
Below is the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` code in the `CategoriesTableViewController` (the first table):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CatTableViewCell *cell = (CatTableViewCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CatTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
   }
```

And here is the code in the ViewController that instantiates these two tableViewControllers:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    UIView *categoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [categoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(60,0, 100,-200)];

    UIView *articlesView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [articlesView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,50, 400,400)];

    CatBarTVC *categoryBar = [[CatBarTVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    categoryBar.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
    categoryBar.view.autoresizesSubviews=NO;


    ArticlesTVC *articles = [[ArticlesTVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [articlesView addSubview:articles.view];
    //[self addChildViewController:articles];

    //[articlesView addSubview:articles.view];

    [self.view addSubview:categoryBar.view];
    [self.view addSubview:articles.view];

    [self addChildViewController:categoryBar];
    [self addChildViewController:articles];

    categoryBar.view.frame =CGRectMake(0,0, 500,70);
    articles.view.frame =CGRectMake(0,50, 400,400);

}
```

Comment: You say you have two UItableviews, but I don't see your code distinguishing them. Each UItableview should have each own outlet.

Comment: I have updated my post with the relevant code.

Comment: do you have 2 of these `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in the same `ViewController`? Thats not going to work how does the OS know which one relates to which table

Comment: I have edited for clarity - these code segments belong in separate TableViewController classes.

Comment: Alright, so if you have a UITableViewController instead of a UITableView, then the UITableViewController is responsible for the datasource and delegate of each tableView and not your UIViewController. So any calls to reload the datasource (i.e. reloadData of the UITableView) should be made in your UITableViewController and not your UIViewController

Comment: @LefterisL This is currently how its being done. The UIViewController just instantiates the TVC classes and the rest is handled inside them.

Comment: Why are you initializing a new View Controller in your ViewDidLoad? `UIVC = [[UIViewController alloc]init];`

Comment: Its actually unused. I forgot to take it out before posting. I've Edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Like I said, you need to reload the TableView from the TableViewController you have, so you have to use this `[articles.tableView reloadData];` when you want to reload the data for that tableView

Comment: 'articles' is an instance created in the ViewController class. I attempt to reload the table in the ArticlesTableViewController class with a 'reload' table method. I've updated my post to illustrate this.

Comment: @lefteris: If I understand you correctly I must not call    [articles.tableView reloadData];    from the ViewController where the TVC object is instantiated, but from the TVC class itself?

Answer (score 0):

I see numerous problems In the code. Please look at the comments in the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Suggestion: Try to keep identifier in ArticlesTableViewCell if you want to use it in more than one table view controller. Don't use _tableView. _tableView is iVar. You should use it only in getters, setters and in init methods.
    static  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Don't call "self.myTableView" of one specific tableView but for current one that is apassed by argument (tableView).
    ArticlesTableViewCell *cell = (ArticlesTableViewCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // You override here existing cell. Try to use if(cell==nil) before creating new cell.
    cell = [[ArticlesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.articleList valueForKey:@"enclosure"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        if (imgData) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (image) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // You should call [cell setNeedsDisplay to inform app that this view have to be redrawn.
                    cell.enclosure.image = image;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // No need to call this on global quele. You should call this directly (e.g. cell.dataLabel = self.articleList[@"pubDate"][indexpath.row];)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [cell.dateLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[[self.articleList valueForKey:@"pubDate"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] waitUntilDone:NO modes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
        [cell.headingTextView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[[self.articleList valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] waitUntilDone:NO modes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
        cell.headingTextView.editable = NO;
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have made these changes accordingly. Thanks. Can you please ellaborate on the first comment you made regarding iVars, and did I make the correct changes?

Comment: Instead of `self.myTableView` use `tableView` whenever you can (e.g. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`